# Flux with multiple ajax requests

Tags: ajax, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I have a React component, `<Profile/>`, for displaying the currently-selected user.

Upon `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUpdate`, I check the Flux store for a user.

If the user is missing, or if the user exists but its `userId` doesn't match the `userId` in the url, I call the Flux action `getUser(userId)`.

The problem is, this call can be triggered multiple times due to `componentWillUpdate` being called multiple times.

My temporary fix is to keep track of pending ajax requests, keyed by `userId`, and if one is already underway, I don't issue another.

This feels hacky, though, and I'm wondering if this is a common problem (and recommended solution) or if my architecture needs improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling a Flux store in `componentWillUpdate`. `componentWillUpdate` is for any preparations you need to do before a render. By the time React calls `componentWillUpdate` it has already determined that something (props or state) has changed, and that the component should update, so that's not the time for fetching more data.

You should instead be calling the Flux store in `componentWillReceiveProps` (assuming the user id is passed as a prop to the component).

Comment: Makes sense, and thank you for the info. Same problem remains, though. Namely, `componentWillReceiveProps` is called > I request data > it's called again > I request the same data = Infinite loop. I presume that there's a property that changes as a result of the ajax call (even before the ajax is returned), triggering the loop, but I don't see it. Moreover, the same problem would exist (in theory) if you have 2 distinct components, both requiring the same data, either one of which capable of requesting it. How does one component know not to issue the same request if it's already underway?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps won't get called unless a new user id is passed in as a prop. What are you doing that causes the multiple duplicate requests?

Comment: I think I just figured it out. I was passing `{...this.props}` instead of explicitly declaring a few properties for the component. My `flux` object was passed down as a result, so I'm thinking that a change in that object caused the loop. It's working now that I've removed it. Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, not fixed. Despite passing only the required properties, the method is called again and again. Not sure why. Logging the two properties (`props.user` and `props.creations`) doesn't show any change from one call to the next. http://i.imgur.com/n3Jr035.png

Comment: Finally got it working by issuing the request only if `this.props.userId !== nextProps.userId`. Still not sure why `componentWillReceiveProps` is called when the props haven't changed, though.

Comment: Are you sure that the props objects are truly deeply equal? React doesn't trigger a re-render if the state or props hasn't changed.

Comment: @AndersEkdahl That's not true; React can't know if props or state have changed or not, as you may have objects that have reference equality but not value equality (thanks JavaScript). Unless you use `shouldComponentUpdate` (or a mixin like `PureRenderMixin`) React must assume you will re-render.

Comment: @BinaryMuse You're quite right, don't know where I got it from that React does a deep equality check.

Answer (score -1):

what you are trying to do is an application logic rather than view logic. So, it's better to move your logic to action/store (refer flux architecture to know more about stores) and emit an event once you get response which will update the view component.